# Why is this Typescript erroring "This expression is not callable"?

Tags: typescript

I have the following Typescript code and the IDE is telling me that "This expression is not callable. Type 'Pick<IUserContext, "clearAllLoginData">' has no call signatures." but I don't understand why.

To my understanding, the `clearAllLoginData` parameter of the `logout` function should be of type `() => void`, since it is `Pick`ed from the `IUserContext` interface.

Any pointers appreciated!

```
interface IUserContext {
    id?: number;
    email?: string;
    fname?: string;
    lname?: string;
    slname?: string;
    companyId?: number;
    companyName?: string;
    clearAllLoginData: () => void;
    setAllLoginData: () => void;
  }


interface LogoutParams {
    clearAllLoginData: Pick<IUserContext, "clearAllLoginData">;
    afterLogout?: () => void;
}

export const logout = ({ clearAllLoginData, afterLogout }: LogoutParams):void => {
    clearAllLoginData(); // <---- Error: "This expression is not callable"
    if (afterLogout) {
      afterLogout();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[What `Pick` does is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)

> Constructs a type by picking the set of properties Keys (string literal or union of string literals) from Type.

In other words - it creates an object type from another object type.

```
Pick<IUserContext, "clearAllLoginData">
```

will result in a type which is:

```
{
  clearAllLoginData: () => void;
}
```

It will *not* give you a type of

```
() => void
```

`Pick` isn't the right tool here. You need something like this instead:

```
interface LogoutParams {
    clearAllLoginData: IUserContext["clearAllLoginData"]
    afterLogout?: () => void;
}
```

Comment: Another way would be to extend it:
`interface LogoutParams extends Pick<IUserContext, "cleanAllLoginData"> { ... `